# Remove images in .docx file

Tags: java, image, xwpf

Do we have the option to remove pictures from `.docx` file in java using `xwpfdocument`? Please reply me since I'm trying to do it for past one week.
Code tried:

```
public static void imageProcess(XWPFDocument document) throws IOException
    {
        List<XWPFPictureData> pic=document.getAllPictures();
        Iterator<XWPFPictureData> iterator=pic.iterator();      
        if (pic.size()>0)
        {   
            for (XWPFParagraph para : document.getParagraphs())
            { 
                List<XWPFRun> runs = para.getRuns();
                for( XWPFRun run : runs ){
                    run.getCTR().removeDrawing(0);
                }
            }
            }
        }
```

Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.removeElement(Xobj.java:2200)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.remove_element(Xobj.java:2230)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTRImpl.removeDrawing(Unknown Source)
    at com.util.DocxUtil.imageProcess(DocxUtil.java:326)
    at com.util.DocxUtil.main(DocxUtil.java:60)
```

Comment: If you've been trying to do it for a week, please **state** what you have tried. That way we won't waste our time suggesting things you already know don't work.

Comment: There is no documentation that states on how to remove images from a docx file.  I doubt if POI even supports removing pictures. And the only snippet I had tried from some question just doesnt work.

Comment: public static void imageProcess(XWPFDocument document) throws IOException
     {
      List<XWPFPictureData> pic=document.getAllPictures();
      Iterator<XWPFPictureData> iterator=pic.iterator();  
      if (pic.size()>0)
      {  
       for (int i=0;i<pic.size();i++) {
       for (XWPFParagraph para : document.getParagraphs())
       { 
        List<XWPFRun> runs = para.getRuns();
        for( XWPFRun run : runs ){
         run.getCTR().removeDrawing(0);
        }
       }
       }
      }
     }

Comment: but it threw error
    
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.removeElement(Xobj.java:2200)
     at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.remove_element(Xobj.java:2230)
     at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTRImpl.removeDrawing(Unknown Source)
     at com.util.DocxUtil.imageProcess(DocxUtil.java:326)
     at com.util.DocxUtil.main(DocxUtil.java:60)

Comment: @Sherin: Please edit your question and add your code and exception to the **question**.

Comment: Why no one is responding? is remove picture not possible with xwpfdocument?

Comment: Because the question seemed interesting , i did  a little recon for you and like you mentioned there is almost nill info on internet about removing an image from docx using xwpfdocument . All the questions regarding this are unanswered. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23789739/apache-poi-remove-picture-in-xwpfdocument . If i was in such a situation , i would keep a copy of the project in the present state to try if anyone answers but would move on with the project and try other api's .

Comment: Also instead of trying to remove images i would try to see if i can create a new doc and copy only text to that. Maybe convert the doc to another format like simple text,html etc first which would allow me to remove images and then reconvert to word doc.

Comment: If we reconvert to word doc can we preserve formats? and also regarding other api, Do we have other api which perform image remove than xwpfdocument? Preserving format is mandatory in all the cases@Raj

Comment: The link below gives a list of paid and free api used for doc convertion. https://angelozerr.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/how-to-convert-docxodt-to-pdfhtml-with-java/ This link below has some code for " how to delete all images from a document" using apose. http://docs.aspose.com:8082/docs/display/wordsjava/com.aspose.words.BookmarkStart.remove+method

Comment: docs.aspose.com:8082/docs/display/wordsjava/  shows connection refused error. @Raj

Comment: I can open the link fine from my system . If you cant try searching for "com.aspose.words.BookmarkStart.remove method" on google. Open the first link that shows up..

Answer (score 2):

If you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on a call where you try to remove item #0, then your list is obviously empty. So either do an emptiness check on all the drawings in your `Run` object, or use a for loop - which won't execute if your `List<CTDrawing>` is empty.

```
for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
    CTR ctr = run.getCTR();
    List<CTDrawing> lst = ctr.getDrawingList();
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++) {
        ctr.removeDrawing(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
        for (XWPFRun run : paragraph.getRuns())
                {
                     CTDrawing []  arr = run.getCTR().getDrawingArray();

                     for(int k=0; k<arr.length; k++)
                     {
                         run.getCTR().removeDrawing(k);
                     }

                }
```